# Is there an entire function satisfying the following criteria?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a function holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying the following:
$f(\frac{1}{n})=(-1)^n\sin(\frac{1}{n}), \;\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$

Could we say that if $f$ is entire then $f^2=\sin^2(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ by Identity Theorem? Then obtain a contradiction by choosing a continuous root of $f$?

Comment: Do you know about the identity principle? I think you can find a sequence of roots of $f$ that accumulate to $0$ on the positive real axis based off your assumption that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n \sin(1/n)$

Comment: Yes, however the examples I thought of were $\exp(\frac{\pi i}{z})\sin(z)$ or $\cos(\frac{\pi}{z})\sin(z)$, both of which are not defined at $0$ so that we cannot use the theorem

Comment: Those don't constitute as appropriate examples since they aren't holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. You're trying to find a holomorphic function on all of $\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy the mentioned criterion

Comment: Exactly. I cannot think of other examples, hence why I am asking about looking at $f^2$

Comment: Why are you saying you cannot invoke the identity principle on $f$? You're assuming $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ if you proceed with contradiction to show that this statement is false.

Comment: I did not say I cannot invoke the identity theorem on $f$. I said I cannot think of examples of entire functions that would give a contradiction. I am aware of how contradiction arguments work.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, since $f$ is holomorphic, we have $
f(x) =_{x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k x^k
$, so $f(\frac{1}{n}) = c_0+\frac{c_1}{n} +o(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{(-1)^n}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$ so $c_0=0$ and we get
$$
c_1 = (-1)^n +o(1)
$$
ie. $c_1 - (-1)^n \to_{n \infty} 0$ which is absurd.